# BeautifulSoup Doesn't Get Values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some datas from https://coinmarketcap.com/. I wrote the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source_link = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_link.text, 'html.parser')


names = soup.find_all('p', class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS')
elevenTo_21 = soup.find_all('p',class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 hKkaxT')


for name in names:
    print(name.text)


for values in elevenTo_21:
    print(values.text)
```

In the mainpage the first ten coin names' classes are "sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS".Soup can get their names but after firt ten name the class of names are "sc-1eb5slv-0 hKkaxT" and soup can't get them and doesn't print on the terminal. How can I fix this issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see a class `sc-1eb5slv-0 hKkaxT` on the page

Comment: If you check the source code of 11th to 21th coins' name (<p>tags) class is that.  `<p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 hKkaxT">Uniswap</p>`

Comment: I would recommend using [api](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/listing?start=1&limit=100&sortBy=market_cap&sortType=desc&convert=USD,BTC,ETH&cryptoType=all&tagType=all&audited=false&aux=ath,atl,high24h,low24h,num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,tags,platform,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,volume_7d,volume_30d) instead of scraping it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because the HTML elements that have class 'sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS' returned from server in response of your http(s) request
but the elements that their class is 'sc-1eb5slv-0 hKkaxT' will load by javascript and will not be accessible unless you execute the javascripts of the website

you can see what is HTML response of the server by using this code

```
with open('file.html', 'w') as w:
    w.write(soup.__str__())
```

note: open the file.html in your editor (not your browser) and try to search for classes that you mentioned,
if you see file.html by your browser the javascripts will run and u will see elements that have 'sc-1eb5slv-0 hKkaxT' class

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The page is loaded dynamically, so `requests` won't support it. However, the data is embedded on the page in JSON format, you can find the data by its ID `__NEXT_DATA__`
and convert it to a `dict` where you can access the keys/values

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.find(id="__NEXT_DATA__").string)

print(type(data))  # <-- <class 'dict'>
```

You can also view the data with:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

---

You can also put the data into a pandas `DataFrame` as follows:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.find(id="__NEXT_DATA__").string)

out = []
for d in data["props"]["initialState"]["cryptocurrency"]["listingLatest"]["data"]:
    for dd in d["quotes"]:
        out.append(dd)


print(pd.DataFrame(out).to_string())
```

Output:

```
   name         price     volume24h      volume7d     volume30d     marketCap  percentChange1h  percentChange24h  percentChange7d               lastUpdated  percentChange30d  percentChange60d  percentChange90d  fullyDilluttedMarketCap  dominance  turnover  ytdPriceChangePercentage           tvl
0    BTC  1.000000e+00  7.435695e+05  1.328383e+07  2.016205e+07  1.875829e+07         0.000000          0.000000         0.000000  2021-07-16T20:21:02.000Z          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000             6.697699e+11    46.1490  0.039640                    8.5778           NaN
1    ETH  1.668467e+01  1.240621e+07  2.216363e+08  3.363971e+08  3.129757e+08         0.131511          1.442732         6.260784  2021-07-16T20:21:02.000Z        -17.392809        -27.836744        -48.000748             6.697699e+11    46.1490  0.039640                    8.5778           NaN
2    USD  3.189381e+04  2.371526e+10  4.236720e+11  6.430445e+11  5.982732e+11        -0.562004          0.846454        -4.575392  2021-07-16T20:21:02.000Z        -17.392809        -27.836744        -48.000748             6.697699e+11    46.1490  0.039640                    8.5778           NaN
3    BTC  5.993527e-02  4.656747e+05  6.332705e+06  1.597201e+07  6.995640e+06        -0.131338         -1.422214        -5.891905  2021-07-16T20:21:02.000Z        -20.702005        -43.648769        -20.586552             2.231176e+11    17.2106  0.066566                  161.7263           NaN
4    ETH  1.000000e+00  7.769627e+06  1.056591e+08  2.664876e+08  1.167199e+08         0.000000          0.000000         0.000000  2021-07-16T20:21:02.000Z          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000             2.231176e+11    17.2106  0.066566                  161.7263           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.